# Why is firefox can't play HTML5 Video Element from Localhost?

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

Im try to play a video by HTML5 with the follow code on **localhost** :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
    <title>HTML5 &lt;video&gt; content negotiation test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<video src="Firefox.ogv"  autoplay="true" controls="true">
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
</html>
```

it work perfectly with Chrome,
http://imageshare.web.id/images/60h5p00ixmetpyerd7w.jpg

but why it not work with firefox
[http://imageshare.web.id/images/4bky59ruk8djra8wtmp.jpg](http://imageshare.web.id/images/60h5p00ixmetpyerd7w.jpg)

i Host it on IIS7 and this is my web.config

```
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogv" /> 
    </staticContent>
```

Comment: Links aren't going to the images.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Please check:

1. the firebug net panel and ensure, that Firefox.ogv has really the video/ogg mime-type
2. check the error and networkState property of the video-element in firebugs DOM-Tab
3. Please use either cannonical or empty values for boolean HTML5 attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a problem with the way your MIME types are set up in your .htaccess file you may need to add the following to enable .ogv to be displayed properly

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
```

Firefox tends not to play .ogg video if the mime type is incorrect!

Comment: Also use phpinfo() to ensure that the mod_mime module is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You want "video/ogg", not "video/ogv".

Comment: @user834931 Hard to say, in that case.  You did check that the server is sending the right MIME type now?